# PHP ODBC The I/O package is not thread safe by default

Tags: php, multithreading, odbc

I had a small PHP select script that was working correctly, i replaced my php ini file with another and since then i am getting the following error message :

> Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: ApplicationDiagnosis:Probable I/O
>   race condition detected while copying memory. The I/O package is not
>   thread safe by default. In multithreaded applications, a stream must
>   be accessed in a thread-safe way, such as a thread-safe wrapper
>   returned by TextReader's or TextWriter's Synchronized methods. This
>   also applies to classes like StreamWriter and StreamReader., SQL state
>   HY000 in SQLExecDirect in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\standsafe\dbscripts\sage\importSales.php on line 8

This is my php script

```
<?php
$num_minutes = 10;
ini_set('max_execution_time', (60*$num_minutes));

$conn = odbc_connect("CData Sage50UK Source","manager","mypassword");
$query = odbc_exec($conn, "SELECT * FROM SalesOrders WHERE CustomerReference = '06/08/18' limit 1");

while($row = odbc_fetch_array($query)){

    $json1[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);

}   

echo json_encode($json1);
?>
```

Something must have changed in thew php.ini file but i do not have the old one anymore! Can someone assist with this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, I asked the CData Support Team to look into this to ensure that the issue wasn't with the ODBC Driver. The issue seems to indeed be with the `odbc_exec` function. Can you roll back the changes to the INI file? Can you source the original INI file?

Comment: @JerodJohnson I did think that it was ODBC but then i used the configure tool and that gives the same message so i was wrong about it being the php.ini, it was just a coincidence. I'm so stuck on this and it is halting workflow :(

Comment: If you think the issue is the driver, then the [CData Support Team](https://www.cdata.com/support/submit.aspx) will be your best resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the issue was actually in Sage and was resolved by re-starting sage SData (Tools > Internet Options > SData Settings). Looks like Sage software is simultaneously trying to read or write from the same data file.